# Find value from Table1 where value from Table2 is between rows in Table1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Assume the following structure:

**Items**:

```
ItemId  Price
----------------
1000    129.95
2000    49.95
3000    159.95
4000    12.95
```

**Thresholds**:

```
PriceThreshold  Reserve
------------------------
19.95           10
100             5
150             1

-- PriceThreshold is the minimum price for that threshold/level
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 to return the 'Reserve' based on where the item price falls between in 'PriceThreshold'.

Example:

```
ItemId  Reserve
1000    5
2000    10
3000    1
```

--Price for ItemId 4000 isn't greater than the lowest price threshold so should be excluded from the results.

Ideally I'd like to just be able to use some straight T-SQL, but if I need to create a stored procedure to create a temp table to store the values that would be fine.

[Link to SQL Fiddle for schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e3fb)

It's late and I think my brain shut off, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interested in something like this:

```
select
  ItemId, 
  (select top 1 Reserve
   from Threshold 
   where Threshold.PriceThreshold < Items.Price
    order by PriceThreshold desc) as Reserve
from
  Items
where
  Price > (select min(PriceThreshold) from Threshold)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e3fb/10)

Comment: Awesome. That worked. I knew someone could help my tired brain out.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to use `reserve` as the lower boundary of the range, and use the `lead` analytic function to generate the "next" lower boundry, i.e., the top boundary.

Once you've done this, it's simply a matter of joining with the condition that the price should be between both boundaries. Unfortunately, the `between` operator doesn't handle `null`s, so you'll need to use a somewhat clunky condition to handle the first and last rows:

```
SELECT [ItemId], [Reserve]
FROM   Items
JOIN   (SELECT [PriceThreshold] AS [Bottom], 
               LEAD([PriceThreshold]) OVER (ORDER BY [PriceThreshold]) AS [Top],
               [Reserve] 
        FROM   [Threshold]) t ON 
               [Price] Between [Bottom] AND [Top] OR
               ([Top] IS NULL AND [Price] > [Bottom]) OR
               ([Bottom] IS NULL AND [Price] < [Top])
```

[SQLFiddle solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e3fb/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the lower bound with

```
select i.itemid, max(lo.pricethreshold) as lo
from items i
join threshold lo on lo.pricethreshold <= i.price
group by i.itemid
```

and use this to retrieve the reserve

```
with bounds as (select i.itemid, max(lo.pricethreshold) as lo
                from items i
                join threshold lo on lo.pricethreshold <= i.price
                group by i.itemid)
select i.itemid, t.reserve
from items i
join bounds b on b.itemid = i.itemid
join threshold t on t.pricethreshold = b.lo
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e3fb/21)